# How to join ON IN ALL relations

Tags: mysql, sql

## tag table

```
| id | label |
|  1 | test1 |
|  2 | test2 |
|  3 | test3 |
```

## image table

```
| id |  data |
|  1 | data1 |
|  2 | data2 |
|  3 | data3 |
```

## mapping table

```
| id | tagId | imageId |
|  1 |     1 |       1 |
|  2 |     1 |       2 |
|  3 |     2 |       2 |
|  4 |     3 |       2 |
|  5 |     3 |       3 |
```

I'm trying to find the image that has all tags in common (image.id = 2).

How do I query for it when tag ids 1, 2 and 3 are provided?

(Sorry for the bad question title)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select m.imageId
from mapping m
where tagId in (1, 2, 3)
group by m.imageId
having count(*) = 3;  -- needs to match the number of tags in the `where` clause
```

Comment: Thanks! Suppose that the number of tags are dynamic, is that also possible with the query?

Comment: @AronWoost . . . The tags are coming from *somewhere*, so it depends on how the query is being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it grouping on imageid and checking for the required count of tagid's.

```
select imageid 
from mapping_table
group by imageid
having count(distinct case when tagid in (1,2,3) then tagid end) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Suppose that the number of tags are dynamic, is that also possible with the query?

Comment: sure..maybe you can convert the list of tags into a table and `join` on the mapping_table.